# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) & {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0."}

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, sql-server

I saw plenty of similar questions but I really could not work my way around this time. What I am having issues with, is populating a view with the content of a [certain object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3R5Y.png) in order to update it.  When I press on "Edit", in theory, all the [fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsveq.png) should be automatically inserted. What have I tried so far?

```
        public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(int id = 0)
    {
        if (id==0)
            return View(new Recipe());
        else
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.client.GetAsync(id.ToString()).Result;
            //return ViewJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(response.ToString()));
            return View(response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Recipe>().Result);
            //return View(new Recipe());
        }
    }
```

`return View(response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Recipe>().Result);` - when using this as a return, I am getting this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

After looking the problem up, I tried the following:
`return View(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(response.ToString()));` which got me this error:

> {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0."}

And at this point I am stuck. I would assume that it is trying to deserialize the following JSON:

```
 {
    "id": 5002,
    "name": "Test Recipe",
    "recipeLink": "testlink",
    "category1Id": 7757,
    "category2Id": 7758,
    "category3Id": 7759,
    "category4Id": 7760,
    "recipeById": 1,
    "totalTime": 30,
    "totalTimeUnitId": 1,
    "activeTime": 20,
    "activeTimeUnitId": 1,
    "instructions": "Test Instructions",
    "sourceKey": "Test SK",
    "recipeBy": "TestPerson",
    "insertedAtUtc": "2019-09-04T12:18:48.0466667",
    "isVerified": 1,
    "numPersons": 5
}
```

If needed, here is the code from the API Controller that is handling the operations.

```
 [Route("v1/recipe/{id}")]
    [HttpPut()]
    public IActionResult UpdateList(int id, [FromBody]Recipe recipe)
    {
        var category1Id = 7757;
        var category2Id = 7758;
        var category3Id = 7759;
        var category4Id = 7760;
        var isVerified = 0;
        var recipeBy = "TestPerson";
        var recipeById = 1;

        try
        {
            if (recipe == null) throw new ArgumentException("No data specified");
            //if (newData.Name == null) throw new ArgumentException("No name specified");

            using (var con = _connFactory())
            {
                con.Execute(@"UPDATE dbo.Recipe SET Name=@name, RecipeLink=@recipeLink, Category1Id=@category1Id ,Category2Id=@category2Id, 
                            Category3Id=@category3Id, Category4Id=@category4Id, RecipeById=@recipeById, TotalTime=@totalTime, TotalTimeUnitId=@totalTimeUnitId, 
                            ActiveTime=@activeTime, ActiveTimeUnitId=@activeTimeUnitId, Instructions=@instructions, SourceKey=@sourceKey, RecipeBy=@recipeBy, 
                            InsertedAtUtc=getutcdate(), IsVerified=@isVerified, NumPersons=@numPersons  WHERE Id=@id",
                            new
                            {
                                id,
                                recipe.name,
                                recipe.recipeLink,
                                category1Id,
                                category2Id,
                                category3Id,
                                category4Id,
                                recipeById,
                                recipe.totalTime,
                                recipe.totalTimeUnitId,
                                recipe.activeTime,
                                recipe.activeTimeUnitId,
                                recipe.instructions,
                                recipe.sourceKey,
                                recipeBy,
                                isVerified,
                                recipe.numPersons
                            });
            }
            return Ok(recipe);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the `space` character at the beginning of your pasted JSON example indicate that there's a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark character (aka Preamble) at the beginning of your real JSON data?

Comment: Are you assuming is this json? you cannot check the response.Content to see what's in it?

Comment: @Dom93 I am assuming because I didn't think of checking response.Content. That JSON I put in the original post was the output from the GET method using Postman. Following your advice, after creating a variable in which I put response.Content, I was not really able to see anything that can help. I am a bit dumb with debugging, so any help with this will be kindly welcomed. https://i.imgur.com/mjkoSRY.png

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have a string value where it is expecting an integer, i.e. a character which is not wrapped in quotation marks.

Could you debug to the line `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(response.ToString()));` in Visual Studio and then inspect the contents of "response" in the locals window and post a screenshot to help diagnose the issue?

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

Try adding these steps in before the return, then see what is contained in the `temp` variable:

```
string temp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
```

It will be interesting to see what this holds, maybe then it will show why the data cannot be parsed into a `Recipe` object.

---

**Further edit**

OK, instead of that line that won't execute try adding this code:

```
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var temporaryData = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

See if that will execute and then inspect the contents of tempoararyData variable.

---

**Edit 3**

OK great we can see the data now. I believe the issue is it is coming through as a JSON array and you're trying to deserialize a singular version. I made this demo app to illustrate:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = "[{\"Id\":5002,\"Name\":\"Test Recipe\"}]";
            string data2 = "{\"Id\":5002,\"Name\":\"Test Recipe\"}";

            //This throws an exception
            //DataClass account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClass>(data);

            //This works
            DataClass account2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClass>(data2);

            //This also works
            DataClass[] account3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClass[]>(data);
        }
    }

    class DataClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I believe if you change your code to deserialize an array i.e. `DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe[]>>` hopefully it will work

Comment: Answer to the edit: https://i.imgur.com/S7euSDH.png Unfortunately I am unable to get any information about the temp variable due to this error.

Comment: For the 2nd edit: At this point I am getting the following error: `HttpResponseMessage does not contain a definition for GetResponseStream`. Then I tried using `response.Content` instead but then the problem is that `Cannot convert type System.Net.Http.HttpContent to System.Io.Stream`

Comment: OK one further idea, try `var temp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` and see if it can read it out like that.

Comment: It worked! `"[{\"id\":5002,\"name\":\"Test Recipe\",\"recipeLink\":\"testlink\",\"category1Id\":7757,\"category2Id\":7758,\"category3Id\":7759,\"category4Id\":7760,\"recipeById\":1,\"totalTime\":30,\"totalTimeUnitId\":1,\"activeTime\":20,\"activeTimeUnitId\":1,\"instructions\":\"Test Instructions\",\"sourceKey\":\"Test SK\",\"recipeBy\":\"TestPerson\",\"insertedAtUtc\":\"2019-09-04T12:18:48.0466667\",\"isVerified\":1,\"numPersons\":5}]"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `response` string starts with the Unicode Byte Order Mark character.

For example...

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"{
    'id': 5002,
    'name': 'Test Recipe',
    'recipeLink': 'testlink',
    'category1Id': 7757,
    'category2Id': 7758,
    'category3Id': 7759,
    'category4Id': 7760,
    'recipeById': 1,
    'totalTime': 30,
    'totalTimeUnitId': 1,
    'activeTime': 20,
    'activeTimeUnitId': 1,
    'instructions': 'Test Instructions',
    'sourceKey': 'Test SK',
    'recipeBy': 'TestPerson',
    'insertedAtUtc': '2019-09-04T12:18:48.0466667',
    'isVerified': 1,
    'numPersons': 5
}".Replace("'", "\"");

            //This works...
            var deserialized1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            //Prepend a U+FEFF Byte Order Mark character...
            json = "\uFEFF" + json;

            //This fails with error:
            //Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException:
            //Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ﻿. Path '', line 0, position 0.
            var deserialized2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but in my case, what is the json variable? I tried applying your code for my case but I can't figure out how to avoid getting errors like "Can't convert HttpResponseMessage to string".

Comment: @Questieme Don't worry, no such thing as a stupid question. In your question you used `return View(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(response.ToString()));`, so your `response` object is the JSON variable.

Comment: Alright, I assumed right, then. Well, the problem is that HttpResponseMessage does not have the method `Replace()`. Do you have any hint on how can I do that instead?

Comment: Oh, you're focusing on the wrong part of my answer. The `.Replace()` is there because I started with apostrophe characters in the example JSON, `'`, instead of quotes, `"`, otherwise everywhere you see a `'` I would have had to use `\"` which is just ugly. The important part of the answer is `json = "\uFEFF" + json;` where I intentionally break the JSON by prepending a Unicode Byte Order Mark character. This causes `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to throw your exception because it can't deal with the U+FEFF. i.e.: You need to remove the U+FEFF character from your web service method's JSON.